# Count mismatch with regular expression and exact substring while counting the number of occurrences of the substring?

Tags: python

Why `'tz': 'America/New_York'` and `'tz':\s+'\w+\/\w+'` give different counts of the occurrences of the substring in the string?

The string from where I am trying to count the number of occurrences of the substring ,has been extracted from a Json file.

```
[{'c': 'US', 'nk': , 'tz': 'America/New_York', 'gr': 'MA', 'g': 'A6qOVH', 'h': 'wfLQtf', 'l': 'orofrog', 'al': 'en-S,en;q=0.8', 'hh': '1.usa.gov', 'r': 'http://www.facebook.com/l/7AQEFzjSi/1.usa.gov/wfLQtf', 'u': 'http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22415991', 't': 1331923247, 'hc': 31822918, 'cy': 'Danvers', 'll': [42.576698, -70.954903]}]

import re
d=open("filepath")
str1=d.read()
list1=re.findall(r"('tz':\s+'\w+\/\w+')",str1,re.I|re.M)    
w=open("newfilepath","w")    
for i in list1:    
        w.writelines(i)
        w.writelines("\n")
```

Comment: Why are you matching a RE against unparsed JSON? Would it not be better to parse the JSON and then match against the value of the key?

Comment: True. But I am not familiar with Json so taking the string as it is.

Comment: If all you want is to extract the time zone keys its just `import json`, `for r in json.load(open("filepath")): print r['tz']`

Comment: That's not valid JSON. JSON uss double quotes around strings, not single quotes.

Comment: Use `ast.literal_eval()` instead.

Comment: PLease suggest in terms of regex.

Comment: For json I am getting "AttributeError: module 'json' has no attribute 'load'"

Comment: You shouldn't get that error: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a regexp, use `ast.literal_eval()` to parse a Python literal.

```
import ast
with open("filepath") AS d:
    str1 = d.read()
    list1 = ast.literal_eval(str1)

with open("newfilepath", "2") AS w:
    for i in list1:
        w.write("'tz': " + i['tz'] + "\n")
```

Comment: I want only "'tz': 'America/Los_Angeles'" portion.

Comment: Updated the answer.